# jquery update table values

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I have an app for a bowling game. The players names are listed along with their scores. When the "roll" button is pressed, the scores will update. Problem is, the updated score will not appear on screen unless the page is refreshed.

If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it!

This is what the main play page looks like:

```
Welcome players!

1:  John:   0

2:  Mark:   0

3:  Paolo:  0

Pins :  

Roll: 0
```

this is the UserController.java file:

```
 package ajaxbowlgame;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
 import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
 import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class UserController {
GameProperties gameProps = new GameProperties();
int htmlPlayerNo = 0;

private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
private int currPlayScore;
private int roll;
private boolean showStrike;
private int playerNo = 0; 

@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(){
    return "AddUser";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addUser(@ModelAttribute(value="player") Player player, BindingResult result){
    JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "name", "Name can not be empty.");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        htmlPlayerNo++;
        player.setHtmlPlayerNo(htmlPlayerNo);
        players.add(player);
        res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        res.setResult(players);
    }else{
        res.setStatus("FAIL");
        res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
    }
    return res;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/play.htm", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public String playPage(GameProperties gamePropsIn, ModelMap model) {

    players.get(playerNo).setScore(currPlayScore);
    players.get(playerNo).setRoll(roll +1);
    gameProps.setRoll(roll);
    model.addAttribute("players", players);

    Player currPlay = players.get(playerNo);
    int pins = gamePropsIn.getPins();

    currPlay.getGame().roll(pins);

    if (pins == 10) {
        showStrike = true;
    } else {
        showStrike = false;
    }

    currPlayScore = currPlay.getGame().score();     
    roll = currPlay.getGame().getRoll();

    model.addAttribute("roll", roll);
    model.addAttribute("pins", pins);

    if (playerNo < players.size()-1){
        playerNo++;

    }else{
        playerNo = 0;           
    }
    if (showStrike ) {
        gameProps.setStrikeMessage("Well done, you hit a strike!");
    } else {
        gameProps.setStrikeMessage("");
    }

    return "play";              
}   
}
```

And this is play.jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax-JQuery Bowling</title>
    <script src="/ajaxbowlgame/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function rollBall() {
        var pins = $('#pins').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/ajaxbowlgame/play.htm",  
            data: "pins=" + pins,  
            success: function(response){  
              // we have the response
              $('#pins').val(''); 

            },  
            error: function(e){  
              alert('Error: ' + e);  
            }  
          });
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <h2>Welcome players!</h2>

    <table id = "playerslist">
    <c:forEach var="player" items="${players}">
    <tr><td>${player.htmlPlayerNo}:</td><td>${player.name}:</td><td  id="plScore">${player.score}</td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table> 
<table>
    <tr><td> Pins: </td><td> <input id="pins"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1"><input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="rollBall()"><br/></td></tr>
</table>
    Roll: <span id="roll">0</span>

    <h2> ${command.strikeMessage}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, this is not really a 'game' as such, because the pins knocked are taken in from the keyboard, into a textfield next to the Pins label above(not visible).

Answer (score 0):

When you roll the ball, you call `play.html`. When that call completes, all you do is to clear `#pins`. This is where you have to update your scores; at the `success` callback.

Comment: I was wondering how to do that. I tried replacing the table, but I dont know how to get an updated version.

Comment: You need to make sure that `playPage` returns all the information you need. I don't know what your `ModelAndView` looks like. You'll be able to access it as `response` in the callback; log it to console to inspect it. Once you have the data, you'll be able to access `$('#playerslist tr').eq(indexOfRowToUpdate).find('td:last').text(newPoints);`

Comment: Ok, thanks, what do I do to get the data? I assume 'newPoints' is the data that comes from the response?

Comment: @jchoran: Yes, `newPoints` would be retreived from the `response` parameter. You need to make sure that your `playPage` method yields all the information that you want to use in your callback. Log the response to console to inspect it.

Comment: I dont know if it makes much difference, but I just noticed that the second last return statement, to return a Model and View, is wrong. It is actually commented out, but thats not shown on this page. The only return statement used is the 'return "play"' one.

Comment: By the way, It looks like the jsp itself is being sent as the response.

Comment: @jchoran: If you only return "play" then that's part of your problem. You should make sure to return all the information you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to do that!